# PDFBOX: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: U+0000 is not available in this font's encoding: WinAnsiEncoding

Tags: java, pdf, printing, pdfbox, fontbox

I've been struggling with one problem for 3 days, I don't know what to do next. After updating pdfbox from version 1.8.8 to version 2.0.26 there was an exception when trying to print pdf. It is not present in all scenarios, but in some.

Here is the code:

```
private static void addFooterText(PDPageContentStream contentStream, PdfProperties.AwFuer gesellschaftVon, PdfProperties.AwFuer gesellschaftFuer, PdfDocType docType) throws IOException {
    PDFont font = PDType1Font.HELVETICA;
    contentStream.beginText();
    contentStream.setFont(font, 6);
    contentStream.newLineAtOffset(225, 24);
    String docTypeKsu = getKsuDocType(docType);
    if (!TextConstants.AUDI_BESTELLUNG.equals(docTypeKsu)) {
        String gkzFuer = gesellschaftFuer.getGesellschaftFuer();
        String gkzVon = gesellschaftVon.getGesellschaftFuer();
        String ksuString = KsuTextFrontEnd.getKsuText(docTypeKsu, gkzVon, gkzFuer); // CR819
        contentStream.showText(ksuString); // CR819
    }
}

private static void addFooterTextFinal(PDPageContentStream contentStream, PdfProperties.AwFuer gesellschaftVon, PdfProperties.AwFuer gesellschaftFuer, PdfDocType docType) throws IOException {
    PDFont font = PDType1Font.HELVETICA;
    contentStream.beginText();
    contentStream.setFont(font, 6);
    contentStream.newLineAtOffset(225, 24);
    String docTypeKsu = getKsuDocType(docType);
    String gkzFuer = gesellschaftFuer.getGesellschaftFuer();
    String gkzVon = gesellschaftVon.getGesellschaftFuer();
    String ksuString = KsuTextFrontEnd.getKsuText(docTypeKsu, gkzVon, gkzFuer);
    contentStream.showText(ksuString);
}
```

And another file:

public void create(Map hashmap, OutputStream out, String FormularName)
throws PdfException {

```
    PDDocument pdf = null;
    try {
        pdf = PDDocument.load(new File(FormularName));

        PDDocumentCatalog docCatalog = pdf.getDocumentCatalog();
        PDAcroForm acroForm = docCatalog.getAcroForm();

        List<?> fields = acroForm.getFields();
        Iterator<?> fieldsIter = fields.iterator();

        while (fieldsIter.hasNext()) {
            PDField field = (PDField) fieldsIter.next();
            String value = field.getPartialName().toString();
            if (hashmap.containsKey(value)) {
                field.setValue((String) hashmap.get(value));
            } else {
                continue;
            }
        }

        try {
            pdf.save(out);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            LOGGER.error(e);
            throw new PdfException(e.getMessage());
        }
    } catch (IOException e2) {
        LOGGER.error(e2);
        throw new PdfException(e2.getMessage());
    } finally {
        if (pdf != null) {
            try {
                pdf.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                LOGGER.error(e);
            }
        }
    }
```

I tried to change version of fontbox / pdfbox. I don't know what to do else. Probably U+0000 is null value. Should I somehow avoid this sign. There were no exception in version 1.8.8

Stacktrace in browser:

```
Exception type: class javax.ejb.EJBException
Exception message: javax.servlet.ServletException: See nested exception&#59; nested exception is: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: U&#43;0000 is not available in this font&#39;s encoding: WinAnsiEncoding
User agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/105.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
Stack trace:
javax.servlet.ServletException: See nested exception; nested exception is: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: U+0000 is not available in this font's encoding: WinAnsiEncoding
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:606)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1290)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:778)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:475)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:152)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:94)
    at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:111)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:207)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:207)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:207)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
    at
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:207)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:207)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:207)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.web.Log4jServletFilter.doFilter(Log4jServletFilter.java:71)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:207)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:1021)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1143)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.CacheServletWrapper.handleRequest(CacheServletWrapper.java:82)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:956)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.DynamicVirtualHost$2.run(DynamicVirtualHost.java:280)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.dispatcher.internal.channel.HttpDispatcherLink$TaskWrapper.run(HttpDispatcherLink.java:967)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.dispatcher.internal.channel.HttpDispatcherLink.wrapHandlerAndExecute(HttpDispatcherLink.java:359)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.dispatcher.internal.channel.HttpDispatcherLink.ready(HttpDispatcherLink.java:318)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.internal.inbound.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:471)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.internal.inbound.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:405)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.internal.inbound.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:285)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.internal.inbound.HttpICLReadCallback.complete(HttpICLReadCallback.java:66)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.WorkQueueManager.requestComplete(WorkQueueManager.java:504)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.WorkQueueManager.attemptIO(WorkQueueManager.java:574)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.WorkQueueManager.workerRun(WorkQueueManager.java:929)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.WorkQueueManager$Worker.run(WorkQueueManager.java:1018)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: Yes remove the 0000. This isn't a character. Check your input.

Comment: I don't have this sign in input file. Should I make some replaceAll(); in matcher? Existing one is: `private static final Pattern nonAsciiPattern = Pattern.compile("[^\u0000-\u00ff]");`

Comment: I put the ascii control codes in tempMap: `            tempMap.put("\u0000", ""); // null
            tempMap.put("\u0001", ""); // Start of Heading
            tempMap.put("\u0002", ""); // Start of Text
            tempMap.put("\u0003", ""); // End of Text
            tempMap.put("\u0004", ""); // End of Transmission
            tempMap.put("\u0005", ""); // Enquiry
            tempMap.put("\u0006", ""); // Acknowledgement
            tempMap.put("\u0007", ""); // Bell
            tempMap.put("\u0008", ""); // Backspace` but without changes. Still the same error.

Comment: It is solved after pattern change to: `Pattern.compile("-[\\u0080-\\u00FF]");` Topic closed